# php SELECT where row value contains string

Tags: php, mysql, get, where-clause

I have a string has item_id from $_GET request

Example

```
item_id = 12;
```

In MySQL, in the topping table I have a row with not integer value like so:

`item_id = "4, 8, 12, 92, ..."` which is hold many items

I want to show all toppings belongs to this item_id

I use this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topping WHERE item_id LIKE "%$item_id%")
```

but it seems not work 100%

I need some thing Like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topping WHERE '$item_id' IN item_id ");
```

I know the last query will not work, but I type it to clear my question

any idea, please
Thanks

Comment: how do you say 1st query not working 100%?

Comment: Also use mysqli, mysql is removed from php7.0

Comment: ```"SELECT * FROM topping WHERE item_id LIKE '%$item_id%'"```maybe is a problem related to the single/double quotes

Comment: yeah @GummaMocciaro i too think so

Comment: you might want to read about [Database Normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php). With a normalized DB you will not have comma separated values in a single column, therefore making your question obsolete

Comment: To add to @Cashbee's comment: This is bound to fail unless when searching for `2` it is supposed to return rows that contain `92`, `12`, `21`, etc.

Comment: You should normalise your database, but failing that remove the spaces after the commas and then use the function FIND_IN_SET().

Comment: @Kickstart FIND_IN_SET() works fine, Thanks